# What will happen to System.web when we host the asp.net web application in Cloud Azure?

Tags: .net, model-view-controller

Since System.web is used for hosting in IIS and what happens to the current applications which mainly hosted in Azuer?. Does system.web deprecated ?

Answer (score 0):

It require System.Web as in Azure it uses IIS.

There are mainly three ways to host web application on Azure

1. As Website
2. Cloud Computing (Web role)
3. Virtual Machine

In, all these ways it uses IIS and Windows server OS. You can take RDC for option 2 & 3 and make changes in IIS as well